# How cellForRowAtIndexPath can reuse formatters (to improve scrolling)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

Allocating NSDateFormatter (or NSNumberFormatter) is relatively slow and
cellForRowAtIndexPath runs for every cell.
So, allocating formatters in cellForRowAtIndexPath can be a significant contributor to jerky scrolling.

To smooth scrolling, I tried  allocating them outside cellForRowAtIndexPath,
by making them a class variable and allocating them in viewWillAppear and releasing them in viewWillDisappear (see code below).
But that produce leaks in the formatters.

Where is the best place to declare/allocate/release formatters used in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

```
//in myNavigationViewController.m:
NSDateFormatter *myDateFormatter;                            

-...viewWillAppear...{                       
    if(myDateFormatter){                    //Solution: add this check.
        [myDateFormatter release];
    }
    myDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];                          
    [myDateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [myDateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    if(locale){                             //Solution: add this check.
        [locale release];
    }
    locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    [myDateFormatter setLocale:locale];       
}
-...cellForRowAtIndexPath... {
    cell.myDateLabel.text =  [myDateFormatter stringFromDate:_date];            
}

-...viewWillDisappear...{  
//    [myDateFormatter release];             //Solution: remove this line 
}
-...dealloc {
    [myDateFormatter release];               //Solution: add these 2 lines.
    [locale release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't leak at all so long as you remember to deallocate it in `-dealloc`.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed by a) removing the release from viewWillDisappear, b) adding to -dealloc, c) checking for myDateFormatter at viewWillAppear, and d) doing the same for 'locale'. I posted the 'Solution' in the code above. Many thanks!